# How do I pass the std::env::vars() object into a function

Tags: rust, actix-web

### What I'm trying to do: pass env vars to a function:

I have a function which takes the std::env::vars() object and returns a database configuration object, like so:

```rust
pub fn config(mut vars: Vars) -> Config
{
    let mut result: Config = Config::new();
    result.dbname = vars.find(|kv| kv.0.eq("DB_NAME"))
        .map(|kv| kv.1);
    result.host = vars.find(|kv| kv.0.eq("DB_HOST"))
        .map(|kv| kv.1);
    println!("database host: {:?}", result.host);
    result.password = vars.find(|kv| kv.0.eq("DB_PASSWORD"))
        .map(|kv| kv.1);
    println!("database password: {:?}", result.password);
    println!("env password: {:?}"
             , vars.find(|kv| kv.0.eq("DB_PASSWORD"))
             .map(|kv| kv.1));
    result.port = vars.find(|kv| kv.0.eq("DB_PORT"))
        .map(|kv| kv.1)
        .map(|string| string.parse::<u16>().ok())
        .flatten();
    println!("database port: {:?}", result.port);
    result.user = vars.find(|kv| kv.0.eq("DB_USER"))
        .map(|kv| kv.1);
    result.manager =
       Some(ManagerConfig { recycling_method: RecyclingMethod::Fast });
    result
}
```

### The problem: the Vars object is empty when passed

All of the above print statements show `None` for the given variables.

However, I know those variables are being set because when I print from the same object in main, the variables all show up:

```rust
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    println!("vars:");
    for (key, value) in std::env::vars() {
        println!("    {key}: {value}"); //works as expected
    }
    println!("env password: {:?}"
             , env::vars().find(|kv| kv.0.eq("DB_PASSWORD"))
             .map(|kv| kv.1));
    let port = environment::port(env::var("PORT"));
    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            .app_data(
                Data::new(environment::config(std::env::vars()) //does not work as expected
                    .create_pool(None, tokio_postgres::NoTls)
                    .expect("Error initializing connection pool"))
            )
            .route("/", get().to(index_controller::index))
            .route("/username-available", post()
                   .to(user_controller::username_available2))
            .wrap(session::middleware())
    })
        .bind(("0.0.0.0", port))? 
        .run()
        .await
}
```

### The question: why can I print std::env::vars() from main but not from a function?

The output of the program is, puzzlingly, as follows:

```bash
huntergatherer3-web-1       | vars:
huntergatherer3-web-1       |     PATH: /usr/local/cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
huntergatherer3-web-1       |     HOSTNAME: 22f204119a79
huntergatherer3-web-1       |     DB_HOST: database
huntergatherer3-web-1       |     DB_NAME: huntergatherer
huntergatherer3-web-1       |     DB_PASSWORD: postgres_password
huntergatherer3-web-1       |     DB_PORT: 5432
huntergatherer3-web-1       |     DB_USER: postgres_user
huntergatherer3-web-1       |     PORT: 8082
huntergatherer3-web-1       |     RUST_LOG: debug
huntergatherer3-web-1       |     RUSTUP_HOME: /usr/local/rustup
huntergatherer3-web-1       |     CARGO_HOME: /usr/local/cargo
huntergatherer3-web-1       |     RUST_VERSION: 1.71.0
huntergatherer3-web-1       |     HOME: /root
huntergatherer3-web-1       | env password: Some("postgres_password")
huntergatherer3-web-1       | Got port 8082.
huntergatherer3-web-1       | database host: None
huntergatherer3-web-1       | database password: None
huntergatherer3-web-1       | env password: None
huntergatherer3-web-1       | database port: None
huntergatherer3-web-1       | database host: None
huntergatherer3-web-1       | database password: None
huntergatherer3-web-1       | env password: None
huntergatherer3-web-1       | database port: None
```

Comment: `find` takes a mut reference and advances the iterator until it finds the value. So after you try to find the port, the vars iterator might very well be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Vars` implements `Iterator`. Advancing an iterator is a mutating operation; it consumes the item at the front of the iterator. In your function, you use `.find()` repeatedly, which advances the iterator until the item is found, **discarding the items that it skips.**

In other words, unless `Vars` produces the environment variables in *exactly the same order your code searches for them* you will skip over variables you want later and they will no longer be available.

If you want to take a `Vars` as an argument, you could simply iterate over `vars` and assign the results based on the current key, something like this:

```
pub fn config(vars: Vars) -> Config {
    let mut result = Config::new();

    for (key, value) in vars {
        match key.as_str() {
            "DB_NAME" => result.dbname = Some(value),
            "DB_HOST" => result.host = Some(value),
            // and so on...

            // Catch-all arm to discard irrelevant variables.
            _ => {}
        }
    }

    result
}
```

There are other approaches as well, such as collecting `Vars` into a `HashMap<String, String>` or using [`std::env::var()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.var.html) to fetch each variable one at a time.

Answer (score 4):

[`Vars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/struct.Vars.html) is an [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) which is a single-pass abstraction.

When you call `.find()` looking for `"DB_NAME"`, it will iterate through elements until it finds a matching element and return that. Based on your output it should find that correctly and put that in `result.dbname`. But when you call `.find()` again looking for `"DB_HOST"`, it has already iterated past that element when it was looking for `"DB_NAME"`. It will continue to search for it from that point until the end without finding it. And then since all elements have been consumed, further `.find()` calls will find nothing.

You can choose to make a new iterator each time:

```
result.host = std::env::vars()
    .find(|kv| kv.0.eq("DB_HOST"))
    .map(|kv| kv.1)
```

Or it would be better to just use [`std::env::var()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.var.html) to get each value:

```
result.host = std::env::var("DB_HOST").ok();
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to be able to pass configuration as an argument, you should `collect` the `Vars` and pass the resulting container into the function.